# Why does my WebView doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

Well, I am totally a beginner, I was trying to do some exercise for webview. However, I can't find what problem it is. Can someone helps me? Thanks.

Here is my java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)
    ;
   Uri uri = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);

    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

And here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jinyu.webview">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my log:

```
4-16 22:52:03.234 23525-23525/com.example.jinyu.webview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.jinyu.webview, PID: 23525
                                                                       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.baidu.com }
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1798)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
                                                                           at com.example.jinyu.webview.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-16 22:52:04.687 23525-23525/com.example.jinyu.webview I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23525 SIG: 9
```

Comment: you did not load  url on web view ?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm follow this tutorial :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** (for future visitors) :  add `http://` or  `https://` before actual `url`.

Shortest way to achieve this is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

add `"http://"` or `"https://"` to your url.